# Как нарисовать в терминале линию?

Tags: c++, linux, графика, ncurses, терминал

Мне нужно нарисовать 10 линий . Из одной точки по одной линии в 10 других точек. Использую библиотеку ncurses желательно было бы найти решение именно с использованием этой библиотечки,пишу под линукс на C++.

Пишу небольшую игрушку. 10 на 10 "Лучников". нужно нарисовать анимацию так сказать выстрела,для начала хотелось бы просто линию от одного лучника к другому.

Comment: Ну гуглится же в полсекунды: [алгоритм Брезенхэма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0). Там даже готовый код и картинка анимированая имеются...

Comment: Этот вариант у меня есть,но я бы хотел что то воде LineTo из библиотеки Windows.h

Comment: До чего же ленивый программист пошёл... Там писанины на 10 строчек. Напишите и назовите `Line(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)`, делов-то на пару минут. А в родной библиотке у них всё равно только горизонтальные и вертикальные линии, если на склеролжу.

Comment: О чем вы? Я вас не совсем понял.

Comment: Э... Вы не понимаете, как имея перед глазами 10 строчек готового алгоритма и библиотеку ncurses написать свою функцию для рисования линии? Подсказываю. Поставить курсор в нужную позицию - функция `move(int x, int y)`, вывести символ - `addch(const chtype ch)`.